# add a function with parameters to a hook

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to run a function according to the programming language when I open a source code file using the following. I have to pass the language-specific `str` to the `foo` function. How can do it in the `add-hook` statement?

```
(defun foo (str)
   (blahblah...))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'foo)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [described in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) (first hit on Google for "emacs add-hook"):

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (foo "foobarbaz")))
```

Comment: What if one wants to remove the function from the hook?

Answer (score 8):

Use the built-in `apply-partially`:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (apply-partially #'foo "spam with eggs"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that mode hooks usually don't have any arguments. The good news is that here's what [(emacs) Hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) section of manual has to say about your situation:

> Most major modes run one or more "mode hooks" as the last step of initialization.

So, I didn't test it myself, but I'm pretty sure you can write a generic hook that will inspect `major-mode` variable and do the mode-specific actions instead.